# Issue with new Cypher 3.1 head() function

Tags: neo4j, cypher

We are using the new Cypher 3.1 head() function and are seeing some unusual (wrong?) behavior when it is used in a RETURN statement after an OPTIONAL MATCH command. It looks like values that the labels that don't match in the optional match negatively affect the data already collected from the head() perspective, while working as expected for the rest of the RETURN statement. Any ideas on what we're doing wrong or is this an unintended consequence in the Neo4j engine?

```
MATCH (productLine:ProductLine)-[:CHILD]->(product:Product)-[:CHILD]->(application:Application)-[:MATCHES]->(:Rule {name: 'Tier-0 Application'})
 WITH  productLine,
   application
OPTIONAL MATCH (application)-[mr:MATCHES]->(:Rule {name: 'Multiple Regions'})
 WITH  application,
   mr,
   productLine
RETURN
   productLine.name AS ProductLine,
   head([(productLine)-[:PRODUCT_MANAGER]->(person:Person) | person.name]) AS ProductLineManager,
   mr.numServers,
   application.id AS AppId
```

Here's what we see:

```
ProductLine ProductLineManager  mr.numServers   AppId
PL1 null    null    IN000041
PL2 LAST,FIRST  6   AP010024
PL3 LAST,FIRST  6   AP107752
PL4 LAST,FIRST  11  AP106560
PL5 null    null    AP012190
```

Comment: Couple of questions: 1. Have you tried it with 3.0? The [`head()`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/cypher/#functions-head) function was provided in 3.0 as well. 2. Can you please provide a sample dataset and preferably simplify your query a bit?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a bug related to pattern comprehension, not the head() function, when there are rows generated by an an OPTIONAL MATCH.

I was able to reproduce the bug using the movies graph as a base.

I created a [bug for this](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/8606) on the Neo4j issues tracker, complete with examples.

As a workaround, it looks like using DISTINCT on either the last WITH or on the RETURN may cause it to return expected results.